# Is lambda function in C language

Tags: c, lambda

Is in C language lambda function or I have to write it by my own.
I was searching on internet and haven't find anything only C++ and C#.

Comment: Short answer: No. C doesn't have what other languages call lambdas. However you can do some interesting things with function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the theoretical sense is not a lambda language because you don't have a true lambda type which is able to be passed around and behaves itself like a real value.

But with function pointers you can obtain pretty similar results:

```
typedef int (*lambda)(); // defines lambda as a type which is a pointer to a function that returns an int

int foo() { return 5; }
int bar() { return 10; }

lambda function;
function = foo;
function = bar;

int result = function();
```

Comment: I think that this answer confuses functions-as-first-class-citizens and lambdas.